# When resizing window elements move after paragraph take more space

Tags: responsive-design

this is a small project where I am trying to make a responsive web design. everything works until the screen resize and in some sizes some of the element move after the paragraph take more space but are not align with the rest of the element.  this is the link in github: https://github.com/jesusjavierm1/Project_2_Responsive_Layout

thank you so much for any help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the page [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adjust yours accordingly. Primary you should add the essential code directly in the question instead of linking it. Thanks!

Comment: It is my first time asking a question by this platform so I did not how to make one. Thank you for the suggestion about how to make one. I posted the link because I think it is easy to see from the source. if you want to see how the webpage render  you can do this: replace github.com with rawgit.com, and remove /blob/'. then it is easy to inspect the webpage on the browser of your preference and see what it was the problem that I was talking about.  anyway I just solve the problem and I will post the answer.

Comment: You are probably right about your suggestion to try it directly in the browser with the  adjusted URL. The problem with external linking is that those pages change or vanish after some time and questions beside answers become useless for future-use. If in contrary the essential parts are described here, questions and answers are long-lasting.

Answer (score 0):

I just find out that the elements can be align vertically. So I solve the problem like that:

```
.container {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

this keep the elements in their place. no matter if I resize the page.

hope this help someone